# uiimageview refreshing all other imageviews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm making an iphone app and I made a method that creates a new `UIImageView` programmatically and it's working great (well.. somewhat great) BUT obviously theres an issue.

Whenever the method gets called, every other `UIImageView` that I created in the storyboard gets refreshed, meaning, they all get placed back to where I placed them originally on the storyboard (they're supposed to be moving randomly)

heres the method

```
- (UIImageView *)shootNewBullet {
    UIImageView *newBullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, playerShip.center.y,15,3)];
    newBullet.Image=[UIImage imageNamed: @"bullet2.png"];
    newBullet.hidden = NO;
    [bulletArray addObject:newBullet];
    [self.view addSubview:newBullet];
    return newBullet;
}



 heres where the method gets called
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
                if (point.x > 101) {
                bullets = [self shootNewBullet];
            }
}
```

if more code is necessary to give good answers please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a consequence of using auto layout (you can turn that off in IB to see if this is the problem). When using auto layout, you shouldn't set any frames. If you do, as soon as the view needs to be redrawn, all frames will be reset to the frames defined by the constraints. If you want to leave auto layout turned on, then you should do any changing of size or position by modifying the constraints rather than directly setting frames.

Comment: thank you for the descriptive answer, can you tell me what you mean by "modifying the constraints" (I'm a newbie still :) )

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, IB is Interface Builder (a storyboard or a xib). Constraints are a powerful but complex system, that I can't explain here. You should read Apple's documentation on them and/or look at the 3 videos on the subject from the WWDC 2012.

Comment: cool stuff, so the easy fix right now is to turn autolayout off, I just tried it and it worked